Application Compiler: Not able to run this app to package Code and create an Executable in Matlab
I have a Matlab file , which defines the variables in the Simulink model and then runs it. A Simulink.SimulationInput Object is used to this end.
The code i have used is a simple one.
simIn = Simulink.SimulationInput("Model");
simIn = simulink.compiler.configureForDeployment(simIn);
simIn = setModelParameter(simIn,RapidAcceleratorUpToDateCheck="on");
input1 = 1;
simIn = setVariable(simIn, "input1" , input1);
simOut = sim(simIn);

Running it in Matlab doesn't lead to any errors. However when i try to create an executable using Application Compiler, the following error message pops up
Unrecognized function or variable 'input1'.
Error using buildRacTarget
Variable 'input1' has been deleted from base workspace.
The only way for me to prevent this error is to define the variable in the command window beforehand i.e before running the Application Compiler to create the executable. However this is not a usefull solution for my purposes.
I have tried multiple approaches like:

Using the evalin and assignin functions
Using a 2nd Matlab script called initial.m, which defines the variable input1 and then passes it into a .m (which is a function script with the definition function model(input1) that defines the Simulink.SimulationInput object and runs the simulink model. Once again, this works perfectly in Matlab and Simulink but cannot be compiled into an executable.
However, these approaches haven't worked.

My question is , how can I fix it? Why is the variable defined in the .m file being deleted? Why doesn't this problem occur when executed in Matlab and Simulink?
Hope you can help me out.
Happy Holidays!
